# Appending multiple files into one file

Tags: unix

I append multiple data files into a single data file using the `cat` command. How can I assign that single file value into a new file?

I am using the command:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 > Newfile.txt
AnotherFile=`cat Newfile.txt`
sort $AnotherFile | uniq -c
```

it showing error like can not open AnotherFile
How to assign this newfile value into another file?

Comment: You want to use paste.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign to another file"?  `cp Newfile.txt yetanotherfile.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Original answer to original question

Well, the easiest way is probably `cp`:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 > Newfile.txt
cp Newfile.txt AnotherFile.txt
```

Failing that, you can use:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 > Newfile.txt
AnotherFile=$(cat Newfile.txt)
echo "$AnotherFile" > AnotherFile.txt
```

#### Revised answer to revised question

The original question had `echo "$AnotherFile"` as the third line; the revised question has `sort $AnotherFile | uniq -c` as the third line.

Assuming that `sort $AnotherFile` is not sorting all the contents of the files mentioned in the list created from concatenating the original files (that is, assuming that `file1`, `file2` and `file3` do not contain just lists of file names), then the objective is to sort and count the lines found in the source files.

The whole job can be done in a single command line:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 | tee Newfile.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Or (more usually):

```
cat file1 file2 file3 | tee Newfile.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

which lists the lines in increasing order of frequency.

If you really do want to sort the contents of the files listed in `file1`, `file2`, `file3` but only list the contents of each file once, then:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 | tee Newfile.txt | sort -u | xargs sort | sort | uniq -c
```

It looks weird having three sort-related commands in a row, but there is justification for each step.  The `sort -u` ensures each file name is listed once.  The `xargs sort` converts a list of file names on standard input into a list of file names on the `sort` command line.  The output of this is the sorted data from each batch of files that `xargs` produces.  If there are so few files that `xargs` doesn't need to run `sort` more than once, then the following plain `sort` is redundant.  However, if `xargs` has to run `sort` more than once, then the final sort has to deal with the fact that the first lines from the second batch produced by `xargs sort` probably come before the last lines produced by the first batch produced by `xargs sort`.

This becomes a judgement call based on knowledge of the data in the original files.  If the files are small enough that `xargs` won't need to run multiple `sort` commands, omit the final `sort`.  A heuristic would be "if the sum of the sizes of the source files is smaller than the maximum command line argument list, don't include the extra sort".

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do that in one go:

```
# Write to two files at once. Both files have a constantly varying
# content until cat is finished.
cat file1 file2 file3 | tee Newfile.txt> Anotherfile.txt

# Save the output filename, just in case you need it later
filename="Anotherfile.txt"

# This reads the contents of Newfile into a variable called AnotherText
AnotherText=`cat Newfile.txt`

# This is the same as "cat Newfile.txt"
echo "$AnotherText" 

# This saves AnotherText into Anotherfile.txt

echo "$AnotherText" > Anotherfile.txt

# This too, using cp and the saved name above
cp Newfile.txt "$filename"
```

If you want to create the second file all in one go, this is a common pattern:

```
# During this process the contents of tmpfile.tmp is constantly changing
{ slow process creating text } > tmpfile.tmp

# Very quickly create a complete Anotherfile.txt
mv tmpfile.tmp Anotherfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

make file and redirectin this in append mode.

```
touch Newfile.txt
cat files* >> Newfile.txt
```